# Recent apps button not working on Motorola Nougat 7.0

Tags: 7.0-nougat, multi-user, motorola

I recently added another user to my Android device. I am using 7.0. Now, recent apps button is not working, i mean... Sometimes it do sometimes don't.

Comment: The 2nd part warrants a separate question.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue bro. You nailed it though we need further answers.I have one solution to make it work again though the problem goes back after a minute or two. I do manual screen shot,pressing the vol+power for my phone.